# What's the while loop within the ExpressionTokenizer for in an ExpressionCalculator?

Tags: java

Hello this is part of a simple ExpressionCalculator java code. I don't seem to understand why the while loop is needed. Could someone explain its function to me?

The full code: https://github.com/yuxiaosun/Big-Java-Late-Objects/tree/master/13-Recursion/expressions

```
public class ExpressionTokenizer {
    private String input;
    private int start;
    private int end;

    public ExpressionTokenizer(String input) {
        this.input = input;
        this.start = 0;
        this.end = 0;
        this.nextToken();
    }

    public String peekToken() {
        if (this.start >= this.input.length()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return this.input.substring(this.start, this.end);
        }
    }

    public String nextToken() {
        String r = this.peekToken();
        this.start = this.end;

        if (this.start >= this.input.length()) {
            return r;
        }

        if (Character.isDigit(this.input.charAt(this.start))) {
            this.end = this.start + 1;

            **while (this.end < this.input.length() && 
            Character.isDigit(this.input.charAt(this.end))) {
                this.end += 1;
            }**
        } else {
            this.end = this.start + 1;
        }

        return r;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it does is make sure that the token will return all digits that follow as one token:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExpressionTokenizer et = new ExpressionTokenizer("123 + 5 + 4");
    while(et.peekToken() != null) {
        System.out.println(et.nextToken());
    }
}
//tokens are 123, +, 5, +, 4
```

Without the loop, it would not find 123, but just 1. That's all it does.

Comment: Thank you. Good answer. Although I now know what it does I'm still unsure where exactly in the process of using this calculator this while loop is required.